# Role creation with alter privilege

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Hi I am creating a SSIS package that truncates table as part of ETL process.  A role needs to be defined with the alter privilege and the service account added to the role

Could somebody show how do i go about it

```
USE CoreReferenceStaging
exec sp_addrole  'alterpermissions', 'INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de'  
exec sp_addrolemember 'alterpermissions', 'INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de'
GRANT ALTER ON [dbo].[theTable] TO [alterpermissions]
```

Comment: Why are you creating roles?   Get your DBA to do it.

Comment: The DBA has asked me to do it. I would need to test it on the Dev and the release it to other enviornments

Comment: Creating roles is Admin, not development.  Post your question at dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps to follow; if you've already done some of them just omit them:

```
create login [INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de] from windows;

use CoreReferenceStaging;
create role alterpermissions;
grant alter on dbo.theTable to alterpermissions;

create user [INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de] from login [INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de];
exec sp_addrolemember 'alterpermissions', 'INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de';
```